# How long should I retain my tax information in Canada?

Tags: canada, taxes, document-retention

What is required by law?

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/46344/32127

Answer (score 2):

From CRA website:

> Generally, you should keep your supporting documents for six years.  Have the receipts and documentation to support your claims ready in case you are selected for review.

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/kpng/menu-eng.html