# For how many years after I file my tax do I need to retain my documents

Tags: taxes, canada-revenue-agency

I have copies of t4 and rrsp slips sitting in my tiny condo and eating up valuable storage space since 2009.

Can I throw them away? How many years after you file a return are you required to keep your documents in case CRA wants to see them?

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/2586/32127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRA suggests keeping them for 6 years : http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/kpng/menu-eng.html

Comment: In the US,  I'd have suggested 7 years.